# How to import data from XML to R?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, import

I am a newbie in XML and R and would like to ask you for a help. I need to extract data from XML into a dataframe in R. The XML file is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Report xmlns="Tlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" txtHeader="Table" Name="Tlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds" xsi:schemaLocation="Tlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds http://nwlph01/ReportServer_HISTORIAN?%2FTemplates%2FPublic%2FTags%2FTlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True">
 -<table1 textbox7="Flags" textbox6="Quality" textbox5="Value" textbox4="Timestamp" textbox2="Tag name">
  -<Detail_Collection>
    <Detail Flags="8392704" Quality="128" TimeStamp2="3758.203125 " TimeStamp="3/13/2019 3:15:00 PM 3/13/2019 3:15:00 PM" TagName="SystemArchive\0101___FIT101G/UM.PV_Out#Value"/>
    <Detail Flags="8392704" Quality="128" TimeStamp2="3771.9267578125 " TimeStamp="3/13/2019 3:15:01 PM 3/13/2019 3:15:01 PM" TagName="SystemArchive\0101___FIT101G/UM.PV_Out#Value"/>
    <Detail Flags="8392704" Quality="128" TimeStamp2="3783.43823242188 " TimeStamp="3/13/2019 3:15:02 PM 3/13/2019 3:15:02 PM" TagName="SystemArchive\0101___FIT101G/UM.PV_Out#Value"/> 
   </Detail_Collection>
  </table1>
 </Report>
```

I am using following codes:

```
library("xml2")
df <- read_xml("lh_01.xml")
```

But what I receive is:

```
Warning message:
In doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) :
xmlns: URI Tlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds is not absolute [100]
```

Do you have any idea what am I suppose to do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it does not like your xml namespace xmlns="Tlg_Table_Begin_Ende_ValueIds"

Comment: So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Searching Stackoverflow delivers e.g the folloeing [URI is not absolute error](http://das%20-%20w%C3%BCrde%20ainfach%20auf%20%22Vienar%22%20-%20klingt%20eh%20wie%20ein%20Name%20-%20reservieren,%20falls%20wir%20augeteilt) - sorry I am not an XML expert what the error in your specific case may be; my know-how only goes so far as to find your xmlns URI unusual.